# Positive Solutions to Second-Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a solution to

$y′′+y=0$ and/or $y′′−y=0$?

that is everywhere positive?

I know the solution to $y′′+y=0$ is $y(x)=Asinx+Bcosx$ and the solution to $y′′−y=0$ is $y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$.

I think $y''+y=0$ doesn't have a solution that is everywhere positive because the $sin$ and $cos$ leave room for a negative answer.  On the other hand, I think $y''-y=0$ does have a solution that is everywhere positive, because of the nature of $e$.  Could someone confirm if what I'm thinking is true?  If not, where did I go wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, with a caveat: it depends on the domain of your differential equation.  When you solve a differential equation, it's important to specify its domain, e.g., $$y''(x)+y(x)=0, \quad 0<x<1$$ or $$y''(x)-y(x)=0, \quad 0<x<2\pi.$$

Your solutions $$y(x)=A\sin x+B\cos x$$ and $$y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x},$$ where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants independent of $x$, are *general* solutions of your differential equations.  By choosing $A$ and $B$, you're selecting *particular* solutions of your differential equation.  In practice, this often depends on boundary conditions associated with the differential equation, but they may or may not be an issue for your particular problem.

Can you choose $A$ and $B$ so your solutions are positive?  It depends.  This is always possible for $$y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$$ because $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are positive for all $-\infty<x<\infty$, so any positive $A$ and $B$ will do.  However, this may or may not be possible for $$y(x)=A\sin x+B\cos x$$ depending on the domain for the problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't think about the domains.  I'll definitely have to take that into account in the future!